# I need to convert a date range into a set of rows in a redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

For example,
I have a record saying an employee took a holiday from 2020-08-01 till 2020-08-20. This single-row needs to be transformed into 20 rows, one for each day of vacation. How can I do this in a fast and scalable manner, since my tables contain thousands of records which might result in millions of rows in output?

Comment: You can always use a recursive CTE. However, if you want high performance, you can try implementing `generate_series()` yourself.

Comment: A traditional way to do this is to JOIN to a Calendar table that contains one row per day, with a JOIN ON condition that matches the date range. Calendar tables are also great for identifying weekends, public holidays, end of month/quarter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `generate_series()` function as proposed by @The Impaler within a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` clause :

```
SELECT employee_id, holiday
  FROM your_table
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day') AS holiday
```

demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=813d78bdfa39292d7cc9ed2b4e9bc37d)